# MYSQLIMPORT problemas con .csv

Tags: mysql, sql

He terminado varios ejercicios pautados en MYSQL y ahora quería practicar por mi propia cuenta. Me he descargado una base de datos del PES 2021. He creado una base de datos con nombre PES 21 y una tabla con nombre jugadores, con name, age y nationality.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es cuando con mysqlimport intento cargar los datos del csv, me da un error y en la práctica anterior no me dio ningún problema este paso:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi archivo está localizado en C:/Master/PES21.csv, no entiendo cual es el error de sintaxis que comenta, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Quítale los apostrofes en las columnas:

```
columns=name,nationality,age
```